# How to understand the convolution of two distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

The definition of the convolution of two distribution seems too abstract to me and I have trouble understanding it.The book define this as $(F*F_1)(\phi)=F(F_1^{-}*\phi)$,where $F$ and $F_1$ is both distributions defined as $$F(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\phi(x)dx$$while $F_1^{-}$ is the reflected distribution given by $F_1^{-}(\phi)=F_1(\phi^-)$，here $\phi^-(x)=\phi(-x)$.Also,the convolution of a distribution with a test function is defined by $(F*\psi)(\phi)=F(\psi^-*\phi)$.

My question is that by definition the inner part of $$F(F_1^{-}*\phi)\space \text{is}\space (F_1^{-}*\phi)(\eta)=F_1^{-}(\phi^{-}*\eta)\space $$$$\text{but} \space F_1^{-}(\phi^{-}*\eta)=\int f(x)(\int\phi(y+x)\eta(y)dy)dx$$ which is a definite mumerical value $a$.So what does $F(F_1^{-}*\phi)$ exactly mean?It mean $F(a)$?But by definition the domain of definition of $F$ is a function $\phi$ not a number.Could anyone help me out the confusion

EDIT:[image]

Comment: Does your literature really say that it is defined by $F*\psi$ is defined by $(F*\psi)(\phi)=F(\psi^-*\phi)$? Isn't that a theorem? Usually it is defined by $(F*\psi)(x)=F(\psi(x-\bullet)).$

Comment: @md2perpe yours is the first definition,look my edit

Comment: So this should answer your question about what $F(F_1^{-}*\phi)$ means. $F_1^{-}*\phi$ is a function.

Comment: @md2perpe though it's a function,but in the definition of $F$,$F(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\phi(x)dx$,$F_1^{-}*\phi$ correspond to $\phi(x)$,but the domain of definition of former is a function while the latter is $\mathbb R$

Comment: The domain of $F$ is a function, yes. The domain of $\phi$ and the domain of $F_1^-*\phi$ are $\mathbb{R}$ since these are functions. But you apply $F$ to $\phi$ or $F_1^-*\phi$ which are functions.

Comment: @md2perpe I think $F_1^-*\phi$ is still a distribution,as the book says.so its domain is not $\mathbb R$,but still a test function.In the other word, the domain of $F$ is a test function,while the domain of $F(F_1^{-}*\phi)$ is a distribution

Comment: Why do you choose that view of $F_1^-*\phi$ instead of the one that makes sense in the context?